# getting PHP Fatal error: require() while trying to access PHP files from server

Tags: php, android

I can't access my php files from android side or google chrome and i get the following errors in the error_log file :

```
[12-Dec-2016 13:41:53 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(./Classes/Classes.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/shaye/public_html/social/index.php on line 12
[12-Dec-2016 13:41:53 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(./Classes/Classes.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/shaye/public_html/social/index.php on line 12
[12-Dec-2016 13:41:53 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required './Classes/Classes.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/shaye/public_html/social/index.php on line 12
```

And also this is my index.php file :

```
     <?php ob_start(); header("charset=utf-8;");
 $dir = str_replace("index.php","",$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

 $params = str_replace($dir,"",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

 $params = trim($params,"/");

 $params = explode("/",$params);

 if(isset($params[0]) && isset($params[1]))
 {
 require './Classes/'.basename($params[0]).".php";
 $class = new $params[0]();
 $class->$params[1]();
 }
 else
 {
 exit;
 }

 ?>
```

And this is the address of my PHP files in the server :

```
shayea.tk/social/Classes/
```

And I am using MultipartUtility library in android side 
Please help I don't know much about PHP

Answer (score 0):

Check the following line once again

```
require './Classes/'.basename($params[0]).".php";
```

I think the path is not matching it may be like below or give proper directory path.

```
require '../Classes/'.basename($params[0]).".php";
```